# Pin "Run" to taskbar through group policy

Tags: group-policy, windows

Is there are way to pin the "Run" button to taskbar through group policy or a script?
Only the specific items needs to be pinned. The other items are not to be touched.

Partial solutions I found on net:

1. [pinitem.vbs](http://deployhappiness.com/pinning-programs-to-the-taskbar-with-group-policy/) , but can only pin binaries.
2. [The powershell solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739772/how-to-pin-to-taskbar-using-powershell) uses the same mechanism.

Comment: You can "pin" it to the Start Menu with Group Policy by enabling the `Add the Run command to the Start Menu` Group Policy setting under `User Configuration|Policies|Administrative Templates|Start Menu and Taskbar`.

Comment: @joeqwerty Start Menu != Taskbar

Comment: I realize that. That's why I didn't post it as an answer. "Pinning" it to the Start Menu may be as good as you can get.

Comment: Have you tried creating a shortcut under `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`?  Try making a shortcut to `rundll32.exe shell32.dll,#61`

Comment: @Zoredache Looks promising - but it's missing the generic text usually in the window. Any way to show the standart window? Anyway, please make this an answer.

Comment: you might also consider using the address bar instead of the run command.  I believe they are the same shell32 call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used partly the powershell you linked and partly Zoredache's stuff, and found the icon for the shortcut myself (not that huge a deal; I had an example in my start menu).

1. Create a shortcut to `rundll32.exe shell32.dll,#61` or `c:\windows\explorer.exe Shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}` like Zoredache suggested.  Name it "Run."
2. Right-click properties, choose the shortcut tab -> Change icon ->  enter `%windir%\system32\shell32.dll`.  Choose the standard run icon.
3. Run the powershell script:

   $shell = new-object -com "Shell.Application"
   $folder = $shell.Namespace('C:\path\to\run\icon')
   $item = $folder.Parsename('run.lnk')

   $item.invokeverb('taskbarpin')

You can put the icon on a user share (copying it to the workstation first?) and assign the powershell as a login script via group policy.

I tested running the script manually on Windows 7 and Windows 8.  It didn't create duplicates when re-run.

Answer (score 1):

@Zoredache's comment is partially correct, but it's missing some information. Pinned taskband items are actually comprised of two components: a .lnk shortcut in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\` AND a registry entry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband`. You have to have both or it won't work. The registry key format isn't defined, so the easiest way is just pin what you want once by hand and then copy the registry key and shortcut to other systems.

You can use Group Policy Preferences to deploy this en masse. Simply use GPP Registry to deploy the key and GPP Files to deploy the .lnk shortcut. [This article](https://4sysops.com/archives/configure-pinned-programs-on-the-windows-taskbar-with-group-policy/) has some good background information on the topic.

Comment: I already mention that I use pinitem.vbs to pin the items. Your approach has one major flaw: the taskbar pinned items become non-persistent. I just want to make sure that the "Run" icon is always pinned. I don't want to mess with other items.